# How to display all the methods an object has in Atom (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

New to NodeJS and Atom. I am looking for short-cut to display all the methods an object has on ATOM IDE. For e.g in JAVA on Eclipse, if an object is suffixed with a period "." eclipse automatically list down all the methods the class. This makes coding easy.

I have installed atom-ternjs but can see no method on suffixing period (.) operator.